# Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm running a react-native app with an android emulator running normal, but when I use the command "react-native run-android" that launch me this **error**:

> warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse":
>   spawnSync
>   C:\Users\HP-Envy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;/platform-tools/adb ENOENT

Comment: Is the packager running? You can also start it up by itself using react-native start. May be the packager is not starting up at all.

Comment: I fixed this. Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798881/3846287

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```bash
$ adb reconnect
```

This is not necessary in most cases, but just in case, let's reset your connection with your mobile and restart adb server.

Finally:

```bash
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

So, whenever your mobile device tries to access any port 8081 on itself, it will be routed to the 8081 port on your PC.