# I'm getting below problem while running my React-native Application

Tags: android, node.js, adb, react-native

[Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync /home/sumit/Android/platform-tools/adb ENOENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvXDS.jpg)

I also Tried using $ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 but no Luck.

Comment: This happens because your bundle is not running. try running ```react-native start```.

Comment: Okay,So after Running react-native start what should i do.

Comment: Run your application & check whether your bundle open automatically if not try to run bundle manually using ```react-native start```

Comment: Thank you S Dushan I Completed it.Myapp is now running.

Answer (score 1):

Now I am updating my app from RN 0.58 to 0.61 and I was facing the same issue. I use to upgrade RN projects by copy-paste my src to a fresh bare RN project. According to new guidelines for MacOS users I had to remove CLI, upgrade node and switch to use `npx react-native` instead of previous RN CLI.

I figured out that I have to set env variable `ANDROID_HOME` properly - **full path way** in your `.bash_profile` file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/matusalem/libs/android-sdk"
```

**do no use relative path like this**:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="~/libs/android-sdk" // wrong
```